# Can you use Azure AMS V3 for DRM Key Delivery only?

Tags: azure, encryption, video-streaming, azure-media-services

My understanding is that on Azure AMS V2 you can do a hybrid key distribution where you maybe stream your encrypted media content from another server (such as S3) and just use Azure as your key server. [This is my reference for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-keys-and-licenses). But I can't seem to find clear documentation on if this is possible in the V3 api. I would just use V2, but they are ending support in 2 years. All my media is stored in AWS S3 so it wouldn't be possible to distribute my content from Azure. From the documentation it seems like they might have removed this feature in V3, since you need an "Asset", to create a "Streaming Locator" in order to stream from. Any help/documentation on this would be appreciated. The other thought I had... is could I just upload like a placeholder "Asset" to AMS and somehow use that to get a license without actually hosting the real asset there? [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-v-2-v-3-migration-scenario-based-content-protection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately hybrid DRM is not available in v3 API. The answer from Microsoft in this article still stands valid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/515974/use-media-services-to-deliver-drm-licenses-or-aes.html

Comment: Thank you for the info. That is unfortunate. It was by far the cheapest and most straightforward pricing model I've seen.